# Pasar de diccionario de listas a lista de diccionarios con Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, nltk

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
   resultado = {'cantidad': ['1', '2'],
                   'comida': ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'],
              'ingrediente': ['beicon', 'queso']}
```

Y quiero obtener:

```
resultado2 = [{'cantidad': '1',
                 'comida': 'pizza',
            'ingrediente': 'beicon'},
              {'cantidad': '2',
                 'comida': 'hamburguesas',
            'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
```

Estoy intentando esto:

```
salida = {}
for key, value in resultado.items():
    data=[]
    for v in value:        
        salida.update([(key, v)])
    data.append(salida)
print (data
```

)
Pero no me da los resultados esperados, sólo me crea un diccionario:

```
[{'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'hamburguesas', 'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
```

Me pueden ayudar,
Gracias.

Lo pongo en el lugar correcto.

El caso es que siguiendo la respuesta de @fjsevilla tengo ya prácticamente lo que necesito pero me falta una pequeña cosa.
El proyecto inicial era el de crear un array de diccionarios que contenga cada pedido que introduce un usuario usando NLTK.

```
# Introducimos lo que queremos comer, por ejemplo: 
#"quiero 2 pizzas de baicon, 2 hamburguesas con queso,
# un bocadillo de jamón y 4 palmeras de chocolate"

def introducir_pedido():
    pedido = input("¿Que desea comer hoy? ")
    return pedido
pedido = introducir_pedido()
```

Después de aplicarle varios procesos NTKL como segmentación de frases, tokenización, análisis morfológico POS Tagger y RegexpParser obtengo un nltk tree como este:

```
(S
  quiero/VB
  (cantidad 2/CD)
  (comida pizzas/NNS)
  de/IN
  (ingrediente baicon/NN)
  ,/,
  (cantidad 2/CD)
  (comida hamburguesas/NNS)
  con/IN
  (ingrediente queso/NN)
  ,/,
  (cantidad 1/CD)
  (comida bocadillo/NN)
  de/IN
  (ingrediente jamón/NN)
  y/CC
  (cantidad 4/CD)
  (comida palmeras/NNS)
  de/IN
  (ingrediente chocolate/NN))
```

Ahora tengo que convertir ese árbol (que está en la variable comanda) en el array de tantos diccionarios como pedidos (cantidad, comida, ingrediente) haya. He usado:

```
# Función para generar el array de diccionarios con cada uno de los pedidos
def Salida(tree):

    tree_dict = {}
    salida = []
    for nodo in tree:        
        if type(nodo) == tuple: # solo nos interesa aquellos datos de la lista que son tuplas
            continue
        key = nodo.label()
        value = nodo[0][0]
        if key not in tree_dict:
            tree_dict[key] = []
        tree_dict[key].append(value) # aquí tenemos un diccionario con todas las cantidades, comidas e ingredientes

    # generamos array que contenga tantos diccionarios como pedidos haya introducido el usuario
    salida = [dict(zip(tree_dict.keys(), values)) for values in zip_longest(*tree_dict.values())]

    return salida
Salida(comanda)
```

Obteniendo la salida que quiero

```
[{'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'pizzas', 'ingrediente': 'baicon'},
 {'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'hamburguesas', 'ingrediente': 'queso'},
 {'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'bocadillo', 'ingrediente': 'jamón'},
 {'cantidad': '4', 'comida': 'palmeras', 'ingrediente': 'chocolate'}]
```

Sólo me queda una cosa, si el usuario no pone cantidad de la comida, por ejemplo "quiero 2 pizzas de baicon, 2 hamburguesas con queso, bocadillo de jamón y 4 palmeras de chocolate", se debería poner cantidad de la comida con valor a '1' como valor por defecto.

Esto lo intento hacer como ha explicado arriba @fjsevilla:

```
salida = [dict(zip(tree_dict.keys(), values)) for values in zip_longest(*tree_dict.values(), fillvalue="1")]
```

Pero el resultado no es el esperado:

```
[{'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'pizzas', 'ingrediente': 'baicon'},
 {'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'hamburguesas', 'ingrediente': 'queso'},
 {'cantidad': '4', 'comida': 'bocadillo', 'ingrediente': 'jamón'},
 {'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'palmeras', 'ingrediente': 'chocolate'}]
```

No me pone como valor por defecto de bocadillo a 1, me toma la cantidad de comida palmeras y el 1 se lo queda esta comida.

¿Como puedo hacerlo para que el valor por defecto me lo ponga correctamente?
A lo mejor el problema es como recorro el árbol para generar los diferentes diccionarios, que seguro que se puede hacer de una manera mas eficiente, pero no doy con ello.
Gracias.

Comment: Te sugiero darle una ojeada a `zip()`

Comment: Estás sobreescribiendo con el último elemento de cada lista. Tal vez necesitas una aproximación más robusta, como la que menciona @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: Hola Roberto, no había visto la edición, el problema es que si tienes una clave de la forma `'cantidad': ['2', '2', '1']`, no hay forma de saber si el que falta es el bocadillo, las pizzas , las palmeras o la hamburguesas. con `zip_longest` se asume que el que falta es el último simplemente. Pero si partimos de un diccionario con esa lista no hay forma de saber cuál de los tres no se ingresó, otra cosa es que fuera algo como `'cantidad': ['2', '2', '', '1']`. Este inconveniente debe resolverse antes de crear el diccionario porque en este punto hemos perdido ya la información.

Comment: A ver si tengo un momento y miro la función con la que generas el diccionario, porque después de ésto no podemos hacer nada.

Comment: Eso es @FJSevilla, el tema sería que en la creación de tree_dict que cuando encuentre una comida y no tenga cantidad añada cantidad=1, estoy intentando hacerlo pero de momento no doy con ello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede crear un diccionario por cada elemento de las listas:

```py
resultado = {'cantidad': ['1', '2'],
             'comida': ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'],
             'ingrediente': ['beicon', 'queso']}

resultado2 = [{key: value[i] for key, value in resultado.items()} for i in range(len(resultado['cantidad']))]
```

Contenido de resultado2:

```py
[{'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'},
 {'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'hamburguesas', 'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, "salida" debería ser tu lista final dado que requieres una lista de diccionarios. Además la lista "data" que es lo que imprimes al final, la redefines en cada iteración del primer ciclo `for`, por lo que solo tendrá ene cuenta la última pareja clave-valor del diccionario original.

Sin cambiar demasiado tu lógica en canto a recorrer el diccionario original, puedes hacer algo como:

```
resultado = {'cantidad': ['1', '2'],
             'comida': ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'],
             'ingrediente': ['beicon', 'queso']}


salida = []
for key, values in resultado.items():
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        try:
            salida[i][key] = value
        except IndexError:
            salida.append({key: value})
print(salida)
```

No obstante, como comentaba fedorqui en tu pregunta, `zip` es posiblemente la forma más simple y eficiente e conseguir lo que deseas:

```
resultado = {'cantidad': ['1', '2'],
             'comida': ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'],
             'ingrediente': ['beicon', 'queso']}

salida = [dict(zip(resultado.keys(), values)) for values in zip(*resultado.values())]
```

> ```
> >>> salida
> [{'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'},
>  {'cantidad': '2', 'comida': 'hamburguesas', 'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
> ```

Bien puede ser un poco confuso, vamos por partes:

### La llamada `zip(*resultado.values())`

- `resultado.values()`lo que hace es llamar al método `dict.values` que genera una vista del diccionario con los valores, en tu caso sería algo como:

  ```
  [['1', '2'], ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'], ['beicon', 'queso']]
  ```
- En este caso `*` permite desempaquetar la vista, es decir pasamos de:

  ```
  zip([['1', '2'], ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'], ['beicon', 'queso']])
  ```

  a:

  ```
  zip(['1', '2'], ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'], ['beicon', 'queso'])
  ```

  por lo que `zip` recibe en tu caso tres argumentos, que son los valores de tu diccionario.
- `zip()` por su parte recibe un número cualquiera de iterables y genera un iterador que en cada iteración retorna el resultado de tomar el i-ésimo item de cada iterable recibido como argumento.

  ```
  for item in zip(['1', '2'], ['pizza', 'hamburguesas'], ['beicon', 'queso']):
      print(item)
  ```

  > ```
  > ('1', 'pizza', 'beicon')
  > ('2', 'hamburguesas', 'queso')
  > ```

### La llamada a `dict(zip(resultado.keys(), values))`

- `values` es en cada iteración el item generado por el anterior zip, es decir `('1', 'pizza', 'beicon')`, `('2', 'hamburguesas', 'queso')`, ...
- `resultado.keys` nos genera la vista con las claves del diccionario original.
- `zip(resultado.keys(), values)` permite emparejar cada clave con sus valores correspondientes:

  ```
  for values in zip(*resultado.values()):
      for pareja in zip(resultado.keys(), values):
          print(pareja)
  ```

  > ```
  > ('cantidad', 1)
  > ('comida', 'pizza')
  > ('ingrediente', 'beicon')
  > ('cantidad', 2)
  > ('comida', 'hamburguesas')
  > ('ingrediente', 'queso')
  > ```
- `dict()` simplemente toma cada conjunto de parejas clave valor y crea un diccionario con ellas:

  > ```
  > >>> dict((('cantidad', 1), ('comida', 'pizza'), ('ingrediente', 'beicon')))
  >
  > {'cantidad': 1, 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'}
  > ```

Si hay no todas las claves tienen listas de la misma longitud y no queremos perder nada podemos usar `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


resultado = {'cantidad': ['1', '2'],
             'comida': ['pizza'],
             'ingrediente': ['beicon', 'queso']}

salida = [dict(zip(resultado.keys(), values))
          for values in zip(*resultado.values())]
```

> ```
> [{'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'}]
> ```

```
salida = [dict(zip(resultado.keys(), values))
          for values in zip_longest(*resultado.values())]
```

> ```
> [{'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'},
>  {'cantidad': '2', 'comida': None, 'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
> ```

```
salida = [dict(zip(resultado.keys(), values))
          for values in zip_longest(*resultado.values(), fillvalue="")]
```

> ```
> [{'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'},
>  {'cantidad': '2', 'comida': '', 'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
> ```

```
salida = [{k: v for k, v in zip(resultado.keys(), values) if v is not None}
          for values in zip_longest(*resultado.values())]
```

> ```
> [{'cantidad': '1', 'comida': 'pizza', 'ingrediente': 'beicon'},
>  {'cantidad': '2', 'ingrediente': 'queso'}]
> ```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, sugerí `zip()` pero vi que no era automático, sino que necesitaba de algo de cariño para obtener el resultado buscado. Tu respuesta lo describe perfectamente

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @fjsevilla, la explicación es muy buena, estoy empezando con Python y me ha quedado claro. Ya sólo me queda una pequeña parte para terminar lo que quiero hacer. Lo pongo dese el inicio para que esten todos los datos.